# Is there a way to avoid fuel loss caused by vaporization from engine heat?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, propulsion

Concorde had engines directly attached to the wings, close to the fuel tanks. Some fuel was evaporated due to heat. What were the reasons to not use pylons or some cooling system to limit this effect?

[image: Concorde]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "struts" here? Do you have a link or picture?

Comment: Are you asking if the heat from the engines is vaporizing the fuel in the wings?  Therefore causing us to lose fuel?

Comment: ya! iam asking that.

Comment: So real question behind this is how much fuel is lost due to heat from engines mounted,directly next to the tank.

Comment: Not really. He is asking if there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: Lets not forget the wings are acting like giant radiators, especially at 60,000 feet.  Also factoring in is frictional heating at the leading edges at Mach 2.  With adequate heat transfer (conductivity through the airframe), it may not amount to more than a few degrees difference at any one location.  It would be interesting to see how much engine insulation was desirable, or if they did indeed use the frame and fuel as a heat sink.

Answer (score 2):

According to this image of the locations of the Concorde's fuel tanks:

[image: Concorde fuel tank locations]
<sup>Borrowed from: [ConcordeSST.com](http://www.concordesst.com/fuelsys.html)</sup>

and this image of the location of the Concorde's engines:

[image: Concorde engines]
<sup>Also from [ConcordeSST.com](http://www.concordesst.com/inside/6.html)</sup>

It doesn't appear that there is a lot of room for direct transfer of heat from the engines to the fuel tanks.

Also of note, the Concorde's designers intentionally used the fuel for other cooling purposes:

> The fuel is also used as a heat sink for cooling purposes. Surplus heat from the air conditioning and hydraulic systems from the constant speed drive and generator and also from the engine lubricating oil is rejected through heat exchangers to the fuel.
> <sup>--[ConcordeSST.com](http://www.concordesst.com/fuelsys.html)</sup>

Based on this, I would say that the amount of fuel vaporized by engine heat was minimal at best, and, therefore, of no concern.